# remove background color if color is yellow excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which contains a lot of sheets and each one contains some rows with specific background color 
Is it possible to remove background color of all cells or rows which have specific color (yellow in my case) background in a worksheet

[here is an example file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=28547251375822364965)

Comment: better option without VBA with Find and Replace https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2746-excel-find-and-replace-fill-color.html#a1

Comment: yes Slai, it works, by far better than vba option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You have to check for the Range.Interior.Color value of a specific Range. In VBA this would look like this:

```
If ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0) Then
  'Do something
End If
```

`RGB(255,255,0)` is yellow in this case. You can use all other values as well. See [RGB Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1dyw8b(v=vs.90).aspx). To remove the color use this:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
```

If you need further help, please give more detail information about your problem and/or leave a comment.

You might also want to check out these links: [Range.Interior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836210.aspx), [Interior.Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499.aspx).

EDIT: According to your example data, you might want to remove green coloring from various sheets in columns "E","F","G" and "H". The RGB of the green is `RGB(146,208,80)`. This code should do the work:

```
Sub removeColor()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim color As Long
    color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To lastRow
            If ws.Range("E" & i).Interior.color = color Then
                ws.Range("E" & i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
            If ws.Range("F" & i).Interior.color = color Then
                ws.Range("F" & i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
            If ws.Range("G" & i).Interior.color = color Then
                ws.Range("G" & i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
            If ws.Range("H" & i).Interior.color = color Then
                ws.Range("H" & i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws
End Sub
```

EDIT: If you want to check ALL cells for their color use this:

```
Sub removeColor()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell as Range
    Dim color As Long
    color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cell in ws.UsedRange
            If cell.Interior.Color = color Then
                cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        Next cell
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Fabian F, here a link of an example xlsx file which I want to remove green background from cells  [http://www.filedropper.com/example_9]

Comment: please view edit for an example file

Comment: thanks, it works for my example but what if I want to loop through all cells because surely others cells can be colored ?

Comment: I edited again. See the last code example in my answer.

Comment: thanks Fabian F, that all I needed

Answer (score 0):

This might solve youre problem:

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    On Error GoTo nex:
    Sheets(i).Activate
    For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        For k = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
            '65535 equals yellow
            '5296274 equals green
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = 65535 Then ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Next
    Next
nex:
Next
```

The loop goes through all Worksheets and looks for the backcolor in all used cells.

To get the number representing a color you can just color A1 in the desired color and run following code:

```
MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color)
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: this code doesn't work, it send me to the third sheet

Comment: The code is going throuh all sheets activating them so after the code has finished you will be on the last sheet.

Comment: If you want to replace the color green (like in you example file) you need to change the 'If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = 65535 Then' because 65535 would fit the color yellow.

Comment: Coloring a cell's background white is not equal to removing the background color.

Comment: Oh sorry, you´re right. I edited my answer.